# Nuxt newbie - Firebase auth not working on refresh

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have searched and tried out a ton of examples and different things but still totally stuck here -I’ve been tearing my hair out for 2 days on this now…
I have a common-ish issue where my app works fine if I log in and click links, but if I refresh or hit a URL directly in the browser, Firebase seems to think I don’t have an authenticated session.

> **Edit** So after thinking more, *I think* this is happening because on refresh, Vue ***server*** is making the request. On clicking a link, the ***client*** makes the request... Big difference is no session/ cookie is set or sent on the server request. 
>   Is the solution to fire a redirect? or is there a way to send the browser's cookie/ session as the page is loaded? Or do I build some kind of server-to-server authentication between Vue and Firebase and then manage logged in state via Vue/ Vuex?

This is the error FB returns:

```
Error during getting LIST of presentations! FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Here is what I am doing:

Firstly in my store/index.js, we decode a cookie of user data and dispatch it to an action called setUserLoggedIn (I know I have the same value set twice, but leaving it in there fore completeness :) )

This code seems to work as expected (i.e. it is always executed as Nuxt is initiating. We do this so we can be sure we have the user data from the cookie in our Vuex store before we do anything). It decodes the cookie/ send the expected values to setUserLoggedin

```js
    import { getUserFromCookie } from '@/helpers'
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }, { req }) {
    const user = getUserFromCookie(req)
    console.log('This code fires first with user ' + JSON.stringify(user))
    if (user) {
      console.log('Found a user cookie - maybe we can log them in')
      await dispatch('user/setUserLoggedin', {
        email: user.email,
        uid: user.user_id,
        thisUserid: user.user_id
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Then we commit the Login Status and User details back to Vuex’s state through 2 mutations and then affirm the fact the user is logged in with Firebase:

```js
 setUserLoggedin({ commit }, user) {

    commit('LOGIN_STATUS', true)
    console.log(`Re-affirming login user object is ${JSON.stringify(user)}`)
    commit('LOGIN_USER', {
      loginInstanceId: 'a-key-to-track-each-login-session',
      useruniqueid: user.thisUserid,
      emailaddress: user.email,
      uid: user.thisUserid
    })
    return UserService.affirmLogin(user)
  },
```

Finally I tried a check to see if I had a session with Firebase (firebase.auth().currentUser returns undefined). No luck with using other Firebase commands to listen to state change or anything like that either... Literally everything I have tried draws a blank.

```js
  async affirmLogin(myuser) {
    const currentUser = await firebase.auth().currentUser
    console.table(currentUser)
  },
```

I am also setting a token with the Firebase token in it

```js
await firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.emailaddress, user.password)
        .then(() => {
          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            currentUser = user.uid
          })
        })
      const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
      Cookies.set('access_token', token) // saving token in cookie for server rendering
```

I’ve tried a million different things - from configuring my Vuex state/ getters and Firebase commands, through to commenting the life out of my code, debugging, etc. but I **cannot** figure out why this isn’t working. Firebase just seems to ignore or can’t see any existing session on refresh, eventhough I have a cookie and I think data in the Vuex store.

However it DOES work if I make a page I have navigated to through the UI hit the route above (i.e. I make form submit button hit affirmLogin).

I think the issue is that something is not right with my session but I just cannot see what it could possibly be. I am also not sure how Firebase is supposed to collect the userid on refresh. Other examples I have seen seems to have it 'just working' but not for me :( Any help HUGELY appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I think your `setUserLoggedin` action must be async too : `async setUserLoggedin...`

Comment: And then  inside this action: `return await UserService.affirmLogin(user)`

Comment: Thanks but I am afraid that didn't work :( Same error

Answer (score 0):

TBH I don't know Vue, Nuxt, *or* Firebase, but my first guess was that at the point where you ask Firebase to return the **currentUser**, it is not yet fully initialized or something of the sort. Firebase docs seem to agree:

> **Note: currentUser** might also be null because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use an observer to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case.

Have you tried using the authentication state observer? It looks like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

I would recommend setting this up as early in the code as possible, to make sure that you never miss the authentication status change. You could start with something like this:

```
setUserLoggedin({ commit }, user) {
  const userPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        console.log('got user', user);
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  });

  commit('LOGIN_STATUS', true);

  console.log(`Re-affirming login user object is ${JSON.stringify(user)}`);
  commit('LOGIN_USER', {
    loginInstanceId: 'a-key-to-track-each-login-session',
    useruniqueid: user.thisUserid,
    emailaddress: user.email,
    uid: user.thisUserid,
  });

  return userPromise;
}
```

I am quite sure this would not be good enough as a final solution but it might help you get on the right track *if my guess was right*.

Comment: Thanks again - This didn't really make any difference - I actually have (had!) that observer set up too (using async/ await) and it only ever seems to resolve to false. I am not quite sure I understand how it is supposed to continually observe the state in the above syntax as it seems to me as soon as the promise resolves either true or false, then that's it. I get the feeling the fact that the state is not being resolved by the time my code moves on is part of the issue but I just don't know how to verify or fix it.

Comment: You are right - the code will move on after the promise resolves/rejects. The above example is only to see if using the observer might help! : ] However, the observer *should* keep calling its callback even after the promise resolves, so `console.log('got user', user);` would be printed whenever a new user logs in (assuming that's how Firebase works - I don't really know). So if "got user" is *never* printed, it _probably_ means that Firebase does not really see the user and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Yep I thought the same at about hour 2 of trying to get this working :) I've not found a way to make it behave in this manner yet. Maybe the issue is somewhere else, but from what I can see, the session cookie and vuex state are both set with the user identifier when we try and do our authenticated call, so it's not obvious to me why this does not work.

Thanks again I will keep plugging away at this

Comment: I don't want this to turn into a forum, so here's a last thought from me. Unless you are using a special Vuex binding of Firebase rather than the official SDK, it probably is not able to pick up the user details from the store. If I am right, you should probably explicitly inform Firebase that there's a user logged in. In other words, what makes you think that there actually *should* be a currentUser at all?

Comment: Thanks. I've been through the code for countless examples and I can't see how any of them pick up the user details.
I am at a total loss as to what to do now. Thanks for your help - hopefully I will work it out!!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem that received unauthenticated error after refresh or reload, problem was from `propertyName` of user endpoint , If you return user directly , not with object `'user':{...}`, you should put `propertyName : false` in auth options of nuxt config, you can check what result auth will receive by execute this code directly

```
let user = await this.$auth.requestWith(    
    'local',    //strategy name
    null,       //endpoint
    { url: '/api/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false } // options.endpoints.user
);
```

Comment: Thank you - in the end I solved this by forcing certain pages to operate in a SPA- like state. This works as even a refresh does not allow the server request to Firebase to occur. I just ran into too many problems trying to make Nuxt/ Firebase play nicely when sending the request on behalf of the client.